# How to call single api in multiple react component with mixed up server side code?

Tags: reactjs

Below is my nested object json, where i want access the properties in different react component

```
{  
   "Created":"2017-02-09",
   "SenderOrReceiver":"Not developed yet",
   "PageResponsible":"Yogesh Shinde",
   "LastUpdated":"2017-02-09",
   "ExternalLinks":[  
      {  
         "Id":null,
         "Title":"Yahoo",
         "Url":"http://yahoo.com"
      },
      {  
         "Id":null,
         "Title":"Facebook",
         "Url":"http://facebook.com"
      }
   ],
   "InternalLinks":[  
      {  
         "Id":null,
         "Title":"Google",
         "Url":"~/link/23199285feef4501987b5fa452e49b94.aspx"
      }
   ],
   "Appendices":[  
      {  
         "Id":null,
         "Title":"React",
         "Url":"~/link/23199285feef4501987b5fa452e49b94.aspx"
      }
   ],
   "ContactDetails":{  
      "Email":"user@gmail.com",
      "Information":"Aliquam mollis, quam nec suscipit placerat, nibh est efficitur urna, in ornare mauris eros eu tortor. Nulla fermentum hendrerit mi, nec luctus nunc auctor at. Nullam sagittis posuere libero, eget imperdiet neque. Etiam ac lacus diam. Mauris sapien turpis, lobortis non eros in, porttitor dapibus ipsum.",
      "Name":"user1",
      "Telephone":"11234"
   },
   "Subject":[  
      "Lorem"
   ],
   "HeadingLinks":[  
      {  
         "Id":"headinglink1",
         "Title":"Heading1",
         "Url":"/sv/news-page/#headinglink1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my server side index.cshtml (Layout)

```
@model intrav2.infrastructure.ViewModels.Pages.NewsPageViewModel
<div class="l-content_primary" role="main">
    <div id="breadcrumb"></div>
    <h2>@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.CurrentPage.Heading)</h2>
    <div id="newcreatedinfo"></div>
    <div>@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.CurrentPage.Media)</div>
    <p class="preamble">@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.CurrentPage.Preamble)</p>
    <div id="newsHeadingLinks"></div>
    <p>@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.CurrentPage.MainBody)</p>
    @Html.PropertyFor(x => x.CurrentPage.ExtraInformation)

    <div id="newspagecontent"></div>

</div>
<aside class="l-blocks_secondary" role="complementary" id="newsSiderBar"></aside>
```

Now i want, 
Created/SenderOrReceiver property in newcreatedinfo
External and Internal links in newspagecontent
Appendices/Contact in side content on page